# downloading pdf from web service

Tags: c#

I created a pdf. Now I want to download that pdf. So I have the following code to allow users to download the pdf from a web service.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(Description = "Download PDF", EnableSession = true)]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public void downloadPDFNow(string orderID)
{
    try
    {
        string fileName = orderID+ ".pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=foo.pdf");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(orderID+ ".pdf");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End(); //Exception 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But getting exception

> Current = Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

I tried the following code except Response.End(). Then also I cant download the pdf.

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() ;
```

Comment: That is not the actual exception.

Comment: I cant download the pdf.  getting that exception.

Comment: What he means is the error you posted isn't a *real* exception. It's simply the debugger running in release mode *probably*, which is optimizing away your variables.

Comment: `ex.Message` will tell you the exception.

Comment: "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack. "

Comment: Change the configuration mode to Debug, recompile, run, and then post the exception.

Comment: Better yet, add logging and log the entire exception string, including the call stack. You can do this by calling `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: Its in Debug mode only :(

Comment: ex.ToString(); Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: Not getting any exception by using  HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); But pdf is not downloading